# Java RegExpr заменить все вхождения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, replace

```java
System.out.println(sells.get(1).toString()
        .replaceAll("<td>","")
        .replaceAll("&nbsp;","")
        .replaceAll("</td>",""));
```

Нужно заменить данное выражение на одно `replaceAll` с несколькими вхождениями, то есть либо `&nbsp;`, либо `</td>`, либо `<td>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.replaceAll("(<td>)|(&nbsp;)|(</td>)","");
```

Comment: можно и без скобок, `"<td>|&nbsp;|</td>"`